# Destructuring assignment via TypeScript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How should I do something like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { x, y, z} = this.props;
      return (...)
    }
}
```

in TypeScript? For now tslinter shows an Error:

> Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>' has no
>   property 'x' and no string index signature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to define a type for props:

```
interface Props {
    x: string;
    y: number;
    z: string;
}

class App extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    render() {
      const { x, y, z} = this.props;
      return (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: And for components without state it's safer to pass `never` instead of `{}` as the second type assertion.