# Destructuring with array of vars assignment in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following:

```
interface FormValues {
    max: number
}
```

Then, I do:

`let [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({max: 5})`

When I do `console.log(formValues.max)` I get a typescript error.  How do I tell the destructuring call that `formValues` is of type `FormValues` and that `setFormValues` is a function?

This is not a duplicate of this:

[Destructuring assignment in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215470/destructuring-assignment-in-typescript)

or fo this:

[Destructuring assignment via TypeScript in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689181/destructuring-assignment-via-typescript-in-react)

Neither of those answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the type of the state

```
export interface IValueType { max: number }

let [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<IValueType>({max: 5})
```

Comment: This works, but how do I set the return type to be an array of `IValueType` and a function?

Comment: if the return type would be an array : useState<IValueType[]>([{max: 5}]);

Comment: Array like `[IValueType, function]`, an array of the value type in element 0 and a function in element 1

Comment: look at the typescript signature: function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]; (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) useState returns a tuple of a S value, and a Dispatch Function to update the state